# Relationship between representations over $\mathbb R$ and over $\mathbb C$

Tags: representation-theory

Let $\rho:G\rightarrow \text{GL}(V)$ be a representation of dimension $n$ over $\mathbb C$. Denote by $V^\mathbb R$ the space $V$ considered as a vector space over $\mathbb C$ of dimension $2n$. Denote by $\rho^\mathbb R$ the representation of $G$ in $V^\mathbb R$.

How do I show that $\chi_{\rho^\mathbb R}=\chi_\rho+\bar{\chi}_\rho$?

I mainly tried to prove $\rho^\mathbb R\cong\rho\oplus\bar{\rho}$ but with no luck.
I'm not quite sure how to approach it, but I sense it is not a difficult one..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asssume $\{v_1,...,v_n\}$ is a basis of $V$ over $\mathbb{C}$. Then $\{v_1, iv_1,...,v_n,iv_n\}$ is a basis of $V^{\mathbb{R}}$ over $\mathbb{R}$. For every $1\leq j\leq n$ let:

$\rho(g)(v_j)=c_{j1}v_1+c_{j2}v_2+...+c_{jn}v_n$

Then $\chi_{\rho}(g)=\sum_{j=1}^n c_{jj}$ by definition.

Now, write $c_{jk}=x_{jk}+iy_{jk}$. For every $j$ we have:

$\rho^{\mathbb{R}}(g)(v_j)=\rho(g)(v_j)=x_{j1}v_1+y_{j1}(iv_1)+...+x_{jn}(v_n)+y_{jn}(iv_n)$

$\rho^{\mathbb{R}}(g)(iv_j)=\rho(g)(iv_j)=i\rho(g)(v_j)=i(x_{j1}v_1+y_{j1}(iv_1)+...+x_{jn}v_n+y_{jn}(iv_n))=$

$=(-y_{j1})v_1+x_{j1}(iv_1)+...+(-y_{jn})v_n+x_{jn}(iv_n)$

In other words, the $v_j$-coefficient of the vector $\rho^{\mathbb{R}}(g)(v_j)$ is $x_{jj}$, and the $iv_j$-coefficient of the vector $\rho^{\mathbb{R}}(g)(iv_j)$ is also $x_{jj}$. So the trace of $\rho^{\mathbb{R}}(g)$ is:

$\sum_{j=1}^n 2x_{jj}=\sum_{j=1}^n 2Re(c_{jj})=\sum_{j=1}^n (c_{jj}+\overline{c_{jj}})=\chi_{\rho}(g)+\overline{{\chi_{\rho}}(g)}$

Comment: Thanks for the response. I might be missing something but how come the basis of $V^\mathbb R$ contains elements with the complex coefficient $i$? Moreover, $v_j$ in the basis of $\mathbb C$ may as well be a complex vector, how can it be an element of $V^\mathbb R$?

Comment: Additionally, $\rho^\mathbb R$ is over $\mathbb R$, how do we know its characteristic polynomial splits all the way?

Comment: @Khal There is no such thing as "complex vector". As a set $V$ remains exactly the same, it has the same elements as before. The only thing that changed is that now we use real scalars in our linear combinations. For example, $(2i)v+3w$ is not a linear combination in $V^{\mathbb{R}}$. However, $2(iv)+3w$ is a perfect linear combination-every vector (and yes, $iv$ is a vector, it is still an element of $V$. Changing the field doesn't make this vector disappear from the set $V$) is multiplied by a real scalar.

Comment: @Khal As for the second question, I never used the characteristic polynomial in my answer. The trace is well defined in any field-just take a basis, compute its transformation matrix, and the trace is the sum of the diagonal entries. We don't need to use eigenvalues/characteristic polynomials here.

Comment: Just to see if I got this, you mean that in $V^\mathbb R$ the $iv_j$ is just a formal writing?

Comment: @Khal Yes. In $V$ we thought of it as $v_j$ multiplied by the scalar $i$. In $V^{\mathbb{R}}$ we can't express it as $v_j$ times some scalar anymore, but this is still an element of $V$, it didn't disappear from the set. For example, $\mathbb{C}$ itself is a vector space over both $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{R}$. Well, it has the same elements in both cases. The set $\{1,i\}$ is a basis of $\mathbb{C}$ over $\mathbb{R}$. Of course $i$ it not a real number, but it is an element of this vector space. Elements of a basis are vectors, not scalars.

Comment: Very nice! thanks, Mark.